# InnoSetup: path to Start Menu Programs

Tags: inno-setup, startmenu

In InnoSetup there are two constants: {commonstartmenu} and {userstartmenu}, which are expanded as "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" and "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" respectively on my PC under Windows 7.

Can I simply add "\Programs" string to them to get the path of the All Programs folder of common and user Start Menu? Is it guaranteed that All Programs folder of Start Menu is named "\Programs"? If no, how can I obtain its name?

Comment: There is also [`{group}`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts). You may change the last part which by default is `AppName` to custom values by setting `DefaultGroupName` in `[Setup]` section. E.g. `DefaultGroupName=MyAppDeveloper\MyAppName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot assume that it is named "Programs".

`{commonprograms}` is the correct constant to use if you want to refer to "Programs" / "All Programs" directly.

However if you want to install more than one shortcut then it is better to use `{group}` and `DefaultGroupName` as RobeN suggested.

Comment: Many thanks, I searched through Inno Setup Constants list for a few times, but somehow missed {commonprograms} and {userprograms}.